# Despliegue de aplicacion MVC5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

cuando despliego mi aplicación en el IIS local funciona correctamente, pero cuando intento desplegarlo en el IIS de un servidor windows server 2012 (produccion) todos los ajax no funcionan, manda un error como si las url no existieran.
Actualmente llamo la url de los ajax de 2 formas de 2 formas:

1. var url = '@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))' + "/Login/Login";
2. var url = "/Login/Login";
   Qué consideraciones debo tener para desplegar la aplicación y no tener estos problemas?
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desde donde estas entrando? porque dice localhost?

Comment: Es en el mismo servidor que me da ese error cuando examino la aplicacion